# Disable option on soft-keyboard android programmatically

Tags: android, android-activity, android-softkeyboard

I want to know that if possible disable hide option on a soft-keyboard programmatically.

[Hide Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2Gci.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Disable return button
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event){

    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                return true;
        }
    }

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

This code disable, as you can see, the return button. For your case you should replace *KEYCODE_BACK* with another *constant*. I don't know for sure if it is one for option button but you can check the list right here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: I began try with all constants mentioned in [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) but don't work with any.